Disable Weak Cyphers in Azure Basic Plan
I want to disable weak cyphers in my Azure App Services. I found it can be done by changing a variable "minTlsCipherSuite" using the Azure REST API from null to a higher value. Ex: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
This Azure guide shows the steps.
I use Azure CLI from Cloud Shell in Bash and I make some variables.
body='
{ 
  "properties": { 
    "minTlsCipherSuite": "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" 
  } 
}
'

At the end when I call the final command az rest --method patch --body "$body" --uri $uri, I receive Bad Request:
Bad Request({"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"The parameter 'MinTlsCipherSuite' has an invalid value. Details: MinTlsCipherSuite is not supported for 'Basic' sku.  Only Premium or higher plan is supported.","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"The parameter 'MinTlsCipherSuite' has an invalid value. Details: MinTlsCipherSuite is not supported for 'Basic' sku.  Only Premium or higher plan is supported."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"01033","MessageTemplate":"The parameter '{0}' has an invalid value. Details: {1}.","Parameters":["MinTlsCipherSuite","MinTlsCipherSuite is not supported for 'Basic' sku.  Only Premium or higher plan is supported"],"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"The parameter 'MinTlsCipherSuite' has an invalid value. Details: MinTlsCipherSuite is not supported for 'Basic' sku.  Only Premium or higher plan is supported."}}],"Innererror":null})

How can I disabled weak cyphers in Basic or Standard Azure plans?
